# Alphanumeric sorting of ArrayList with HashMap

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` with several objects per index.  I want to sort this list alphanumerically by one object in particular.  The object is "my_id" and the values for this object can look similar to: 1A, 10B, 11B, 2C, 205Z, etc.

I need to sort these to come out: 1A, 2C, 10B, 11B, 205Z.  Where the numeric part is sorted first, then the alpha- part is sorted secondary. 1,2,3,4,5,... A,B,C,D,E,...

I checked out some alphanumeric string sorting that worked really well: 
http://sanjaal.com/java/206/java-data-structure/alphanumeric-string-sorting-in-java-implementation/

Unfortunately I can only get that object to sort and I lose the other objects in my `ArrayList` as a consequence.  I really need a sorting algorithm that can rearrange the `ArrayList` index's by the object of my choosing and not lose the other objects!

Is there a method to do this already out there?  I've been unable to find one.  I think it's useful to add that all the objects in my `ArrayList` are mapped strings: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`

[edit]
I have my array:
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al`

I then store the object:

```
String[] alphaNumericStringArray = new String[al.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
        {
            alphaNumericStringArray[i] = al.get(i).get("my_id");
        }
```

I now sort the string array:

```
// Sort the array now.
        Arrays.sort(alphaNumericStringArray, new AlphanumericSorting());
```

I then put the object back:

```
for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("my_id", alphaNumericStringArray[i]);
                // TODO, need to append the rest of the objects.
            al.set(i, map);
        }
```

I know what you're thinking, I'm not adding all the objects BACK when I re-map it.  This is what I have currently, but what I want is a way to sort the whole list not just the one object "my_id".  I want to rearrange the indexes so I don't have to re-map everything at the end.

Comment: Why do you lose objects? I do not see how you can lose objects by sorting a list?

Comment: **"ArrayList with several objects per index"**, elaborate this...

Comment: could you post your code? maybe you're doing the sorting right but you're not saving your objects.

Comment: @waqaslam the op is refering to a list containing hashmaps

Comment: @UrielArvizu That is what I have in mind, but he failed to mention this important clue anywhere. However, it's still our assumption.  :)

Comment: I added more detail in the edit to the main post, thank you all for the quick replies.

Comment: @waqaslam op misplaced this information at the end of the question.

Comment: @Brandon it's still not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to sort each hashmap in your array list by key values? or are you trying to sort each hashmap in your array list by an object value property? are you trying to sort your hashmaps inside your array list by a key value? If you could clarify your objective we can help to give you an asnwer.

Comment: I have the ArrayList with, several objects.  "my_id", "other_id", "name", "age", "sex", etc.

I want to sort the ArrayList indices by the "my_id" object.  So that the indices get rearranged by the alphanumeric sorting of "my_id".  so I am trying to sort each hashmap in my array list by an object value property!

Comment: I solved the problem, solution posted below.  Thanks for asking the right questions that led to me understanding the problem better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful reconstruction of the Comparator and all the comments I finally figured out how to do this.

**Question:**
To reiterate what my goal is, as well as the solution.  I have an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.  I want to sort the ArrayList by one object in the HashMap.  My HashMap has more than 1 object in it so I want to retain the entire index of the Array.  I also want to sort alphanumerically where numeric values are the first to be sorted, than I sort alphabetically.  i.e., 1,2,3,4,... A,B,C,D,...

**References:** 
http://sanjaal.com/java/206/java-data-structure/alphanumeric-string-sorting-in-java-implementation/

**TL;DR Solution:**
In my custom Comparator function `public int compare(object firstObj, Object secondObj)` I needed to change the String values to HashMap object references/values.  Here the KEY_ID is the object that I wanted to sort by.  Once I did this I used Collections.sort to sort by the HashMap comparator rather than the Arrays.sort (Collections handles ArrayList/HashMaps).

**Code Solution:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;

/** 
 * DOCUMENTATION: 
 * http://sanjaal.com/java/206/java-data-structure/alphanumeric-string-sorting-in-java-implementation/ 
 **/

@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public class AlphanumericSorting implements Comparator 
{
    public int compare(Object firstObjToCompare, Object secondObjToCompare) 
    {
        String firstString  = ((HashMap<String,String>) firstObjToCompare).get("KEY_ID");
        String secondString = ((HashMap<String,String>) secondObjToCompare).get("KEY_ID");

        //String firstString    = firstObjToCompare.toString();
        //String secondString = secondObjToCompare.toString();

        if (secondString == null || firstString == null) 
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int lengthFirstStr  = firstString.length();
        int lengthSecondStr = secondString.length();

        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;

        while(index1 < lengthFirstStr && index2 < lengthSecondStr) 
        {
            char ch1 = firstString.charAt(index1);
            char ch2 = secondString.charAt(index2);

            char[] space1 = new char[lengthFirstStr];
            char[] space2 = new char[lengthSecondStr];

            int loc1 = 0;
            int loc2 = 0;

            do 
            {
                space1[loc1++] = ch1;
                index1++;

                if (index1 < lengthFirstStr) 
                {
                    ch1 = firstString.charAt(index1);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    break;
                }
            } 
            while (Character.isDigit(ch1) == Character.isDigit(space1[0]));

            do 
            {
                space2[loc2++] = ch2;
                index2++;

                if (index2 < lengthSecondStr) 
                {
                    ch2 = secondString.charAt(index2);
                } else 
                {
                    break;
                }
            } 
            while (Character.isDigit(ch2) == Character.isDigit(space2[0]));

            String str1 = new String(space1);
            String str2 = new String(space2);

            int result;

            if (Character.isDigit(space1[0]) && Character.isDigit(space2[0])) 
            {
                Integer firstNumberToCompare    = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(str1.trim()));
                Integer secondNumberToCompare   = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(str2.trim()));

                result = firstNumberToCompare.compareTo(secondNumberToCompare);
            } 
            else 
            {
                result = str1.compareTo(str2);
            }

            if (result != 0) 
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return lengthFirstStr - lengthSecondStr;
    }

    /**
     * ALPHANUMERIC SORTING
     */
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sortArrayList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al)
    {
        Collections.sort(al, new AlphanumericSorting());

        return al;
    }
}
```

**To return the sorted ArrayList:**

```
myArrayList = AlphanumericSorting.sortArrayList(myArrayList);
```

Where,

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrayList;
```

Answer (score 2):

Running the `main` method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> unsorted = Arrays.asList("1A", "10B", "B", "753c", "Z", "M7", "32x", "11B", "2C", "205Z");

        Collections.sort(unsorted, new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

                if (o1.isEmpty())
                    return -1;

                if (o2.isEmpty())
                    return 1;

                String o1number = extractNumberPrefix(o1);

                String o2number = extractNumberPrefix(o2);

                if (o1number.isEmpty())
                    if (o2number.isEmpty())
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    else return 1;

                if (o2number.isEmpty())
                    return -1;

                if (o1number.equals(o2number))
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);

                return Integer.parseInt(o1number) - Integer.parseInt(o2number);
            }

            private String extractNumberPrefix(String o1) {

                String result = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < o1.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(i, i + 1));
                        result += o1.substring(i, i + 1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("sorted = " + unsorted);
    }
}
```

returns:

```
sorted = [1A, 2C, 10B, 11B, 32x, 205Z, 753c, B, M7, Z]
```

Comment: I have the alphanumeric sorting down with a string array `String[]` but what I need is an ArrayList with mapped objects to sort based off an object of my choosing, i.e., `"my_id"`  ex: al.get(i).get("my_id")  <--

Comment: OP wants to sort `HashMaps`, by the value behind one key. The rest you seem to have correct.